# Constructing a rectangle in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and am trying to understand case classes and methods through the following exercise. Any inputs or help would be much appreciated, as I am still getting used to the syntax.

So far, I have attempted the following steps:

a) Create a case class called **Point()** made up of two integers, x and y

b) Create methods **leftOf() and above()** to find out whether a given point is left of/above another point

```
#part a
case class Point(x: Integer, y: Integer) {
#part b
def leftOf(point: Point): Boolean = {
if(x < point.x) return true}
def above(point: Point): Boolean = {
if(y > point.y) return true}
}
```

c) Create a case class rectangle constructed from two points, a **topLeft** and **bottomRight**

d) Create another method called **contains()** that takes a point p and returns true if the point in within the rectangle

e) Create another method called **overlaps()** that takes one rectangle r and returns true if it overlaps with another rectangle

```
#part c
case class Rectangle(topLeft: Point, bottomRight: Point) {
val topLeft: Point = leftOf.x && above.y
val bottomRight: Point = !(leftOf.x && above.y)
val bottomLeft: Point = topLeft.x && bottomRight.y
val topRight: Point = bottomRight.x && topLeft.y

#part d
def contains(p: Point): Boolean = {
if (p.topLeft.x < x < p.bottomRight.x) && (p.topLeft.y < y < p.bottomRight.y) return true}

#part e
def overlaps(r1: Rectangle, r2: Rectangle): Boolean = {
if (r2.topLeft(r1) || r2.topRight(r1) || r2.bottomLeft(r1) || r2.bottomRight(r1)) return true}
```

Comment: "Any inputs or help would be much appreciated" -- Write code that compiles. If you don't understand the compiler errors post **that** on SO.

Comment: For part d: ';' expected but 'return' found.

Comment: @SameSignificance What is the question? What is the problem? What works, what not?

Comment: I wanted to verify if what I've got so far makes sense, since I am still new to scala

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors and bad practices. To name a few, use of `return` [is discouraged in **Scala**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html) - [**case classes** should be `final`](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/tricky_behaviours/final_case_classes.html) - `if` without `else`. _"Integer"_ does not exists, you meant `Int`. **Scala** _(nor any other programming language that I know)_ does not allow you to check for a range like this `p.topLeft.x < x < p.bottomRight.x`, you need `(p.topLeft.x < x) && (x < p.bottomRight.x)`.

Comment: Finally, this: `val topLeft: Point = leftOf.x && above.y` does not make any sense at all. The notation is _object . method_ not _method . object_, you said the variable would be of type **Point** but you are returning a **Boolean**. - In resume, I will try to help you with some of the points, but I would recommend you to read more about the language, specially follow any tutorial / curse / book or something that takes you from the basis.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the implementation of the first 4 requirements as an attempt to show how to write idiomatic **Scala** code.
The last requirement is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
// Part a.
final case class Point(x: Int, y: Int) {
  // Part b.
  def isLeftOf(that: Point): Boolean =
    this.x < that.x

  def isAboveOf(that: Point): Boolean =
    this.y > that.y

  def isRightOf(that: Point): Boolean =
    !isLeftOf(that)

  def isBelowOf(that: Point): Boolean =
    !isAboveOf(that)
}

// Part c.
final case class Rectangle(topLeft: Point, bottomRight: Point) {
  // Part d.
  def contains(point: Point): Boolean =
    (point isBelowOf this.topLeft) &&
    (point isRightOf this.topLeft) &&
    (point isAboveOf this.bottomRight) &&
    (point isLeftOf this.bottomRight)
}

Rectangle(Point(0, 0), Point(5, 5)) contains Point(3, 3)
// res: Boolean = true
```

_(**Note:** This solution contains some bugs, regarding the implementation of `isRightOf` & `isBelowOf` *(transitively, `contains` too)*. Its solution is left as an exercise to the reader)_.

Comment: `isRightOf`/`isBelowOf` may need to consider the coordinate being equal (so that the points of neither left nor right from each-other).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to leave out the return type annotation for such simple cases? I guess that's more of an opinion-based stylistic issue.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't think leaving type-annotations for your "api" methods is a good choice in any circumstances. The type-annotations on api-methods provides an extra layer of error-prevention in your implementation. Ideally you should not leave out the type-annotation unless there is a layer above which enforces the type verification.

Comment: @Thilo That is right, I noticed after posting the answer, but since this seems like a homework and the idea of my answer was mostly show how to solve many of the syntax errors / bad practices, rather than solving the problem itself. I just leave it there. But I will edit the answer to make that obvious.

Comment: @JörgWMittag as Sarvesh Kumar Singh said, IMHO anything that is public should have explicit type signatures, including **methods** _(`defs`)_, `vals` & `lazy vals`, **constants** on the companion objects & **implicits**. It is not only a way of documentation, but a bugs catcher, if you explicitly states what you want as the return, if the implementation is wrong, the compiler will tell you.